# Age defined in excel is showing error "Message: Column 'Age' does not belong to table DataTable."

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I am new to UiPath. I have an excel with 4 columns: First name, Last Name, Age, Email. When data is read from the excel, all the columns are displayed in message log except Age which is an Integer. The error message I get is "Message: Column 'Age' does not belong to table DataTable.".Below is my code for Read Data from excel:

```
"Customer details"+" "
       +customer.Item("First Name").ToString+""
       +customer.Item("Last Name").ToString+""
       +customer.Item("Age").ToString+""
       +customer.Item("Email").ToString
```

Can you please hep with the issue pertaining to printing the Age.

Comment: How did you define the `DataTable` ?

Comment: Check if Age is showed in Debugging.

Comment: @kwoxer- In debug mode I get this message-Log Message: Column 'Age' does not belong to table DataTable.

Comment: @Luuk - In the Read Range activity, I have set MyCustomers as variable in Output->DataTable field

Comment: You should check the definition for `Customer`, as it seems not to have a column/field/... `Age`.

Comment: I changed my column name from Age to Ages and the error went away. Not sure why .. :)

Comment: Odds are good the excel file that was creating the datatable did include a column named Age, but likely with a trailing space, meaning that the code above failed.  When the OP changed it to Ages in the excel file and then the code, problem vanishes like magic